# Blue plate special as metaphor for the Trinity

Tags: catholicism, trinity, heresy

I think this might be the first practical question on C.SE. Please don't close it because it sounds to speculative, I want to know what might be heretical about it according to Catholic doctrine.

I've been mulling over a thesis in my head concerning a wonderful metaphor I can use to explain the Holy Trinity to 7th graders.

> The Holy Trinity is like a Blue Plate special served in an old timey diner.  It is three portions of the same hearty meal wherein one portion precedes the second portion and the second portion precedes the third to make a complete unity in sustenance.  If you removed any part of the meal it would cease to be a blue plate special.

So, is there any reason to consider this a bad metaphor (other than the fact that some prefer meat over potato and some prefer potato over peas).

Comment: I think you need to explain more what the parts (persons) are and why they are that. More detail in how you explain this and being representative of the Holy Trinity.

Comment: Wouldn't this fail the separability criteria? I don't have a full answer so I'm not much help beyond this.

Comment: Still partialism, I think. (Each portion is only 1/3 of the meal.)

Comment: Might be fun to try brainstorming non-heretical explanations of the Trinity in a chatroom ...

Comment: I don't think I can say any more without obviously falling into heresy. Do we say that each person of the trinity is all of God?

Comment: @PeterTurner I think so. From [The Athanasian Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02033b.htm), "And the Catholic Faith is this, that we worship one God in Trinity and Trinity in Unity. **Neither confounding the Persons, nor dividing the Substance**."

Comment: Well the metaphor is that if it were dividable it would cease to be a Blue Plate Special.

Comment: @svidgen - wouldn't your comment about the Athanasian Creed be a suitable answer, with a little flushing out? Why waste it on a comment?  I'm teetering on the edge of thinking this question does need to be closed as primarily opinion-based (Sorry Peter Turner).  It does seem better suited for chat... BUT if someone can score an acceptable answer on it - within guidelines, that would push me to the "Keep it open" camp.  It looks to me like svidgen is already part way there.

Comment: @DavidStratton I don't have a good reference to cite for Partialism other than that ridiculous St. Patrick video. You wouldn't happen to have a reference, would you? Is the heresy known by a more technical name?

Comment: @svi could that be a Lutheran heresy?

Comment: Pretty sure I've heard Fr. Barron say something about it, but not necessarily by that name. ... In any event, this clip *might* be helpful for your 7th graders without heading into heretical territory: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lGUo00j9qvw (He doesn't mention any heresies here. Just explains the Trinity.)

Comment: I suspect that the 7th graders will have more trouble understanding a blue plate special.

Comment: OK. The results from [Is Partialism a real heresy?](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/is-partialism-a-real-heresy) are in. And I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

It sounds like a heretical understanding sometimes called [Partialism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/is-partialism-a-real-heresy), which suggested that the Father, the Son, and the Holy Spirit are parts of the one God. Partialism contrasts the [The Athanasian Creed](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/02033b.htm). Namely:

> And the Catholic Faith is this, that we worship one God in Trinity and
>   Trinity in Unity. Neither confounding the Persons, *nor dividing the
>   Substance*.

And St. Athanasius writes in paragraph 28 of the [Discourse 1 Against the Arians](http://newadvent.org/fathers/28161.htm):

> As we said above, so now we repeat, that the divine generation must
>   not be compared to the nature of men, nor the Son considered to be
>   part of God, nor the generation to imply any passion whatever; God is
>   not as man; for men beget passibly, having a transitive nature, which
>   waits for periods by reason of its weakness. **But with God this
>   cannot be; for *He is not composed of parts*, but being impassible and
>   simple, He is impassibly and indivisibly Father of the Son.**

In the Blue Plate special example, each portion is only part of the meal. Any one individual portion is not *fully the meal*. In the Trinity, each divine person is *fully God*.

Comment: http://www.firstthings.com/blogs/firstthoughts/2013/03/17/the-shamrock-symbol-of-modalism/ read the comments here

Comment: @PeterTurner http://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/17893/is-partialism-a-real-heresy

Comment: A blue plate special is one plate with three hearty servings of something, the food usually overlaps since it's not usually one of those kiddie plates with 3 compartments, but one big blue plate.

Comment: Oh yeah. Not sure why I wrote plate instead of portion. They both start with P ... In any case, same answer. The meal is *divisible* [into parts].

Answer (score 4):

It does sound like Partialism eg akin to the 3 leaf clover idea (see above you-tube for an entertaining explanation of that :) !! )

I prefer the metaphor of a cube to explain the Trinity to those who may need something concrete to assist in their undestanding. There we have Length, Breadth and Height. The Length is NOT the Breadth is NOT the Height. They are separate. Yet they all are partakers of the same stuff of the cube (same essence). And one dimension is not more important than another (they are equal in power and glory).
Also, you cannot ever lose one of the dimensions, for then you do not have a cube any more (all Persons (Father, Son and Spirit) are co-eternal).

When they are a little older, the kids can also have the idea of the Trinity explained using X, Y & Z dimensions for space, or they might like to read the best explanation I have come across from [Calvin's Institutes](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/calvin/institutes.iii.xiv.html).
HTH

Comment: Helps a bit, that's a good analogy, I personally don't like mathematical analogies for explaining things to kids.  They're too impersonal for a Personal God. Also, in not sure partialism is a thing (be careful if you go and look it up, I guess it's a clinical term for some strange fetishes)

Comment: Hadn't heard the cube metaphor before, and may  be the best one yet!

Comment: But then you would have to say the the length *is* the cube, the height *is* the cube, and the width *is* the cube, and that is not true.

Comment: Not too sure about that. I would have said: The length is the length, the height is the height and the width is the width and the cube is the cube, but that's just me.

Comment: In fact without length, breadth and height, the concept of a cube is meaningless.